# Consultar últimos registros por hora

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com dúvidas em extrair dados da última hora do banco mysql, o código abaixo faz a soma de valores na tabela pelo último dia, mais relacionar pela última hora não estou conseguindo fazer.

```
   $busca = mysql_connect("$local","$usuario","$senha") or die("ERRO AO CONECTAR AO MYSQL, VERIFIQUE COM O ADMINISTRADOR" . mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db("$banco") or die("BASE DE DADOS INVÁLIDO");
            $pesquisa = mysql_query("SELECT sum(ProdValor) FROM vendas WHERE data BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE()-30 AND CURRENT_DATE()");
            while($sum = mysql_fetch_array($pesquisa)){
            $soma5 = $sum['sum(ProdValor)'];
            }
            //Mostrando o Resultado

            //$resultado = number_format($soma,2,",",".");

            echo $soma5;
```

Comment: Qual é o formato do campo `data`?

Comment: @Sergio está no formato date.

Comment: Experimenta com `WHERE data >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

Comment: @Sergio atualizei para: `mysql_query("SELECT sum(ProdValor) FROM vendas WHERE data >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");` e não é demostrado nenhum valor, mesmo havendo registros no banco de dados a 1 hora atrás.

Answer (score 2):

Para mim o que [Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) falou deu certo:

```
WHERE data >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Talvez seja porque na estrutura do campo na sua tabela você tenha colocado somente `DATE`, coloque `DATETIME` igual tá aqui pois comigo funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Existe essa forma também:

```
$data_hora_intervalo = 
    date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));

where data>='$data_hora_intervalo'
```